# How do I implement Python asynchronous flow control with RabbitMQ Pika library

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, rabbitmq, pika

I have some Python 3.51 code based on the async example consumer provided by Pika (0.10.0) for communicating with RabbitMQ (3.6.2)(http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html)

Currently queue creation takes a callback, which binds the queue. Binding the queue also takes a callback that it calls on success. This is already something where I'd like to replace the nested callbacks with some kind of waterfall flow control, typical when using something like javascript promises.

Furthermore I have a scenario where a single message can cause the creation of multiple queues and I want to acknowledge the message once all queues are created. This would again lend itself to some sort of flow control, where a function will be called once all the queue creation sequences have completed in parallel.

Right now I'm achieving this with a mix of nested functions and closures. This works, but if possible something with flow control would be much cleaner.

How would I implement this using flow control in Python? Following is a simplified version of my current code.

```
def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    routing_key_components = basic_deliver.routing_key.split('.')
    queue_counter = len(routing_key_components) - 2

    def queues_setup_complete():
        nonlocal queue_counter
        queue_counter -= 1
        if queue_counter == 0:
            self._channel.basic_publish('bar_ex', basic_deliver.routing_key, body, properties)
            self.acknowledge_message(basic_deliver.delivery_tag)

    for i in range(2, len(routing_key_components)):
        sub_key = routing_key_components[i]
        routing_pattern = 'foo.%s' % sub_key
        queue_name = 'foo_%s' % sub_key
        exchange_name = 'bar_ex' % sub_key
        self._channel.queue_declare(self.on_foo_queue_declareok(routing_pattern, 
                                                                exchange_name,
                                                                queues_setup_complete),
                                    queue_name)

def on_foo_queue_declareok(self, routing_pattern, 
                           exchange_name, queues_setup_complete):
    # nested function with closure returned to allow passing additional parameters to the callback function
    def queue_declared(method_frame):
        self._channel.queue_bind(self.on_foo_queue_bindok(queues_setup_complete),
                                 method_frame.method.queue,
                                 exchange_name, routing_pattern)
    return queue_declared

def on_foo_queue_bindok(self, queues_setup_complete):
    # nested function with closure returned to allow passing the 'queue_setup_completed' function
    # to the callback.
    def foo_bound(unused_frame):
        queues_setup_complete()

    return foo_bound
```